# How can I download a dataset in my Windows PC using WGET

Tags: windows, download, wget, gnu

I want to download a dataset from physionet.
I downloaded and set up GNU WGET for windows.
From the command line, I go to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
and ran this command:

> wget -r -np http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/apnea-ecg/

It started downloading files, but they are not in my PC. 
How can I have them to be saved in my PC, in the C drive?

Comment: Can please someone help me, and answer my question